# When creating child, also create parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my project I have two models: Responder (which is basically a message) & Conversation. Responder is a child of Conversation. What I want is that if a user creates a new responder, it automatically creates a conversation for this Responder. The Conversation only has an id.

if the admin then replies on this Responder, the conversation_id for this responder will be the same as the user's responder.

So what I want:

- User/admin creates responder (child), also create the conversation (parent)
- Admin/user uses reply button, conversation.id of responder replied on is passed on to the new responder.

I've looked around a bit, and found some similar questions. But they aren't quite what I want, and I can't figure out how to build around it so it works for me. I feel it's a very simple thing to do, but I really have no idea how and where to start.

Conversation.rb:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responders
end
```

Responder.rb:

```
class Responder < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :text, presence: true

  has_many :receivers
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation

end
```

and my responders controller might it help:

```
class RespondersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :all_responders, only: [:index, :create]
    before_action :check_user
    respond_to :html, :js

    def show
        @responder = Responder.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        #@conversation = Conversation.new
        #@conversation.save #Works, but puts data in database before submitting the form
        @responder = Responder.new
    end

    def create
    @responder = Responder.new(responder_params)

    if @responder.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render partial: "form", errors: responder.errors.full_messages
    end
end

private

    def check_user
        if !signed_in?
            redirect_to new_session_path
        end
    end

    def all_responders
        if current_user
            @companies = Company.all
            if current_user.administrator?
                @responders = Responder.where.not(:user_id => current_user.id)
            else
                @responders = Responder.where(:receiver => current_user.id)
            end
        end
    end

    def responder_params
        params.require(:responder).permit(:title, :text, :receiver, :sender_id, :company_id, :user_id, :conversation_id)
    end
end
```

The mail system is unique where there is a administrator that sends mails as multiple companies (from a drop down list) and users can only send mails to the company. I also don't want to use gems for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with before_create callback to create conversation in Responder class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know this could be done so easily. I did this so when pressing the `reply` button the `conversation_id` gets passed on in the `link_to` to the `new_responder_path`, and is put in a hidden form if available. Then in the model I check with a `before_create` callback once again if there is a conversation_id passed on, if not it gets created. It seems to be working perfectly now, thanks!